# Conditional counts in pandas group by

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe
[image]

I want to reformat it in the following way:

1. Group by name/account/monthly periods
2. Average (mean) balance to two decimal places
3. Average (mean) for transactions to no decimal places
4. Count of days where balance < 0
5. Count of days where Balance > Max credit

So the I apply the following function to make a Series of all the aggregations, and use the Series index as labels for the new columns:

```
 def f(x):
    d = {}
    d['Avg_Transactions'] = x['Transaction'].mean().round()
    d['Avg_Balance'] = x['Balance'].mean().round(2)
    d['Zero_Balance_days'] = (x['Balance'] < 0).count() 
    d['Over_Credit_days'] = (x['Balance'] > x['Max Credit']).count()
    return pd.Series(d, index=['Avg_Transactions', 'Avg_Balance', 'Zero_Balance_days', 'Over_Credit_days'])

month = df.groupby(['Account','Name', 'Month']).apply(f)
```

Which gives the following output:
[image]

But I am getting the conditional counts wrong and instead counting all days.
What would be the proper way to write these?

Comment: Please do not include images of your dataframes which would require someone to manually transcribe the dataframes from the images, but rather include a _small_ subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the __provided__ data. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888) for more information.

Comment: Use `d['Zero_Balance_days'] = (x['Balance'] < 0).sum() ` instead ? That is, `sum()` instead of `count()`   Similarly for the other field

Comment: Hi @bran, and welcome to SO. Please [convert your images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) to something that’s usable − so that other users can help you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try replace your 2 lines with `.count()` to `.sum()`, as follows:

```
d['Zero_Balance_days'] = (x['Balance'] < 0).sum() 
d['Over_Credit_days'] = (x['Balance'] > x['Max Credit']).sum()
```

[`.count()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html) returns number of non-NA/null observations in the Series of boolean index while both `True`/`False` are not NA/null and will be counted as well.

[`.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) returns the sum of entries of `True` since `True` is interpreted as `1` while `False` is interpreted as `0` in the summation.

Comment: @bran  Please consider upvoting my answer if it proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)).